# Is Windows 7's Remote Assistance feature secure?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

Are there known attacks that can intercept an ongoing Remote Assistance session, for example to take screenshots or even worse, impersonate the other computer and send arbitrary keystrokes, or to connect to an inactive session before the real person that is supposed to "assist" me connects ?

*Background : I often use Remote Assistance to show stuff to some friends or to allow them to try/use a program that they either can't or don't want to install on their own machine, and I'm concerned about the security of all this.*

Comment: I feel honor-bound to make you aware that Microsoft's own employees may misuse Remote Assistance in illicit ways. I caught them red-handed once: in the course of a Remote Assistance session to fix a simple licensing issues with MapPoint North America, one of Microsoft's techs began downloading my entire main hard drive. First he lied in broken English & said it wasn't true, till I said I was watching him do it live through Resource Monitor. Then he admitted it but said it was technically necessary. I disabled RDP before & after that precisely because of that kind of vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, assistance in windows 7 is based on RDP.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Assistance

> In Windows 7, WRA is based on RDP 7 and uses Peer Name Resolution
>   Protocol when connecting using the Easy Connect option.

There exists a weakness in win 7 RDP, but its most likely been patched on a updated computer.

http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-0002

> The Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) implementation in Microsoft Windows
>   XP SP2 and SP3, Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Vista SP2, Windows
>   Server 2008 SP2, R2, and R2 SP1, and Windows 7 Gold and SP1 does not
>   properly process packets in memory, which allows remote attackers to
>   execute arbitrary code by sending crafted RDP packets triggering
>   access to an object that (1) was not properly initialized or (2) is
>   deleted, aka "Remote Desktop Protocol Vulnerability."